# Odoo 8 Access Error on computed field using @api.depends

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, erp

I'm trying to add new computed field in customer interface, this field is computed from another field. The result is that I cannot open customer page anymore and I got:

Popup message-: AccessError', u'The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. 
Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: res.users, Operation: read)

The model.py:

```
   class res_partner_custom(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    y_credit_dollar = fields.Float("Total Receivable ($)",readonly=True,compute="compute_credit_dollar")

    @api.one   
    @api.depends('credit')
    def compute_credit_dollar(self):
        for record in self:
            # update the y_credit_dollar field: Access error here
            record.y_credit_dollar = credit/2
```

The View.xml:

```
<record id="yared_customer_accounting_form_id" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">base.partner.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="credit" position="after" >
            <field name="y_credit_dollar"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `for loop` try below code.

```
 @api.one 
 @api.depends('credit')
 def compute_credit_dollar(self): 
      self.y_credit_dollar = credit/2
```

Comment: still have the Access Error probem, it occred once I tried to update the field y_credit_dollar. thank you for ur reply